# Essential singularity and infinitely many zeros of a non-constant holomorphic function $f$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a non-constant holomorphic function such that $f$ has infinitely many zeros in $\mathbb{D}\setminus \{0\}:= \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| < 1, z \neq 0\}$.

How can I show that the singularity at $z=0$ has to be an essential singularity?

I know the standard theorems of holomorphic functions (Casorati-Weierstraß, Picard theorem, ...) but I do not see which of those might help here.

Comment: Show that it can not be a removable singularity or a pole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume the singularity of $f$ in $0$ is not essential. Then there is a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $g: z \mapsto f(z)z^k$ is entire. However, $g$ has infinitely many zeros in $\mathbb{D}$. Those zeros have an accumulation point, so the identity theorem implies that $g$ is constant. But then $f(z) = Cz^{-k}$ for some $C \in \mathbb{C}$ - which does not go well with the assumptions.

Comment: In fact $C=0$, so $f=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $f$ has infinitely many zeros in $\Bbb D$ and since $\Bbb D$ is compact, the set of zeros of $f$ must have an accumulation point $z_0$ in $\Bbb D$. If $z_0\ne 0$, then, by the identity theorem, $f$ would have to be the null function. Therefore, $0$ is an accumulation point of the set of zeros of $f$.

If $f$ had a pole at $0$, then $\lim_{z\to0}|f(z)|=\infty$, and therefore $f$ has no zeros in $\{z\in\Bbb C\mid0<|z|<r\}$ if $n$ is small enough. That's impossible, since $0$ is an accumulation point of the set of zeros of $f$. And if $f$ has a removable singularity at $0$, then near $0$, $f(z)$ can be written as $a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots$, and therefore $\lim_{z\to0}f(z)=a_0$. If $a_0\ne0$, then, by continuity, $f$ is not zero near $0$; that's impossible, since $0$ is an accumulation point of the set of zeros of $f$. And if $a_0=0$ then, since $f$ is not the null function, near $0$ you have $f(z)=a_kz^k+a_{k+1}z^{k+1}+\cdots$, for some $k\in\Bbb N$ and some $a_k\ne0$. But every zero of $f$ must also be a zero of $g(z)=a_k+a_1z+\cdots$, which is impossible, since $\lim_{z\to0}g(z)=a_k\ne0$.